# Get Radius Of Visible Map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Is there any possible way of finding radius of the visible map from the middle point?

[image: Google Map]

I want to get the near places against the center point of the map from an API, and that API require lat,lng and radius. I am able to get lat and lng from center point but couldnt find a way to get radius .

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the Google Maps Android API, you can get the bounds by...

From the map reference, get the `Projection` by [getProjection()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getProjection()). And,

> a projection is used to translate between on screen location and geographic coordinates..

So from the projection, we can use the [getVisibleRegion()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#getVisibleRegion()), and to get the [VisibleRegion](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html) of the map, which contains a [LatLngBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html), which is a class that contains 2 `LatLng` variables, one for the Northeast corner of the bound and one for the Southwest corner.

So the code should look something like this:

```
        googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                LatLngBounds bounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                LatLng northeast = bounds.northeast;
                LatLng southwest = bounds.southwest;

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "ne:"+northeast+" sw:"+southwest;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

=-=-=-=-=-=
edit:

May be I was too naive, given only the NE and SW can solve this problem, but only under the special case where user did not rotate the map or tilt up for the 3D map.

So instead, you can just grab the `VisibleRegion`, which provided 4 variable, farRight, farLeft, nearRight, nearLeft, each represent 4 conners of the area.

Then we can calculate the width and height of the area for that 4 points and pick the smaller one (well, sometime width can be greater than height I guess.)

And for the calculation, we can just use the `Location.distanceBetween(x1,y1,x2,y2,result)` function...

which makes the code look like the following:

```
                VisibleRegion visibleRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();

                LatLng farRight = visibleRegion.farRight;
                LatLng farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft;
                LatLng nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight;
                LatLng nearLeft = visibleRegion.nearLeft;

                float[] distanceWidth = new float[2];
                Location.distanceBetween(
                        (farRight.latitude+nearRight.latitude)/2,
                        (farRight.longitude+nearRight.longitude)/2,
                        (farLeft.latitude+nearLeft.latitude)/2,
                        (farLeft.longitude+nearLeft.longitude)/2,
                        distanceWidth
                        );


                float[] distanceHeight = new float[2];
                Location.distanceBetween(
                        (farRight.latitude+nearRight.latitude)/2,
                        (farRight.longitude+nearRight.longitude)/2,
                        (farLeft.latitude+nearLeft.latitude)/2,
                        (farLeft.longitude+nearLeft.longitude)/2,
                        distanceHeight
                );

                float distance;

                if (distanceWidth[0]>distanceHeight[0]){
                    distance = distanceWidth[0];
                } else {
                    distance = distanceHeight[0];
                }
```

Comment: I was going to say the rest is only a math problem, but I guess I was too naive. by the way, the distance is in meter.

Comment: Definitely the second approach you suggested worked very well. Thank you @kaho

Comment: @kaho As **Think twice code once** said the approach is good but I guess while calculating the height you have mistakenly cosidered the latitude which eventually give the width again. You should consider longitude as **Think twice code once** has done

Answer (score 14):

thank you so much for your answer **@kaho**, it helped me alot (even you calculated the distanceWidth and distanceHeight in the same way).

Clarification:

- **farLeft**  LatLng object that defines the **top left corner** of the camera.
- **farRight** LatLng object that defines the **top right corner** of the camera.
- **nearLeft** LatLng object that defines the **bottom left corner** of the camera.
- **nearRight** LatLng object that defines the **bottom right corner** of the camera.

**EDITED**: I don't know why we made a simple calculation become a bit complicated, the visible radius is just **A HALF OF VISIBLE DIAGONAL LINE**, that's all!

[image]

```
private double getMapVisibleRadius() {
        VisibleRegion visibleRegion = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();

        float[] diagonalDistance = new float[1];

        LatLng farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft;
        LatLng nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight;

        Location.distanceBetween(
                farLeft.latitude,
                farLeft.longitude,
                nearRight.latitude,
                nearRight.longitude,
                diagonalDistance
        );

        return diagonalDistance[0] / 2;
    }
```

I also logged my results to compare with @jossef-harush 's results and it's approximately:

[image]

Comment: what's the number in? radians? I'm getting some really big numbers here, seems like meters

Comment: yep,  the value of **visibleRadius** is in meters

Comment: How to exclude area which is not part of Visible Map/Region? I'm talking about left/right radius curve which is out of visibility.

Comment: @VVB you want to calculate visible rectangle area? it's simple, just calculate it from 4 corner points of *VisibleRegion*

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think your existing answer calculates that way only. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

## Full area, even corners!

I don't see other answers **cover the entire map area;**

see image below, to test it I drew a circle overlay to see the bounds of the calculated radius, it does not cover entire map area.

my modification is quite simple, I've used [Pythagorean theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/854538/160478) to find the suitable radius to contain the map "rectangle".

[image]

```
private double getMapVisibleRadius() {
    VisibleRegion visibleRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();

    float[] distanceWidth = new float[1];
    float[] distanceHeight = new float[1];

    LatLng farRight = visibleRegion.farRight;
    LatLng farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft;
    LatLng nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight;
    LatLng nearLeft = visibleRegion.nearLeft;

    Location.distanceBetween(
            (farLeft.latitude + nearLeft.latitude) / 2,
            farLeft.longitude,
            (farRight.latitude + nearRight.latitude) / 2,
            farRight.longitude,
            distanceWidth
    );

    Location.distanceBetween(
            farRight.latitude,
            (farRight.longitude + farLeft.longitude) / 2,
            nearRight.latitude,
            (nearRight.longitude + nearLeft.longitude) / 2,
            distanceHeight
    );

    double radiusInMeters = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceWidth[0], 2) + Math.pow(distanceHeight[0], 2)) / 2;
    return radiusInMeters;
}
```

Comment: thank man! I figured out my answer is not properly. But I also find out more simple way to calculate the visible radius. we already have coordinate values so we don't need to apply *Pythagorean* that have to calculate distance 2 times for width and height, you can check my updated answer

Comment: How to exclude area which is not part of Visible Map/Region? I'm talking about left/right radius curve which is out of visibility.

Comment: VVB the facto one use case for circle is to use the geo latlong + radius to filter only relevant data from your DB. You can manually filter out the  results that are out of the viewport according to the viewport's rectangle bounding box

Answer (score 2):

For the Kotlin users, call this function from `setOnCameraIdleListener`

```
    private fun getMapVisibleRadius(): Double {
    val visibleRegion: VisibleRegion = mMap.projection.visibleRegion

    val distanceWidth = FloatArray(1)
    val distanceHeight = FloatArray(1)

    val farRight: LatLng = visibleRegion.farRight
    val farLeft: LatLng = visibleRegion.farLeft
    val nearRight: LatLng = visibleRegion.nearRight
    val nearLeft: LatLng = visibleRegion.nearLeft

    Location.distanceBetween((farLeft.latitude + nearLeft.latitude) / 2, farLeft.longitude, (farRight.latitude + nearRight.latitude) / 2, farRight.longitude, distanceWidth)

    Location.distanceBetween(farRight.latitude,
            (farRight.longitude + farLeft.longitude) / 2, nearRight.latitude, (nearRight.longitude + nearLeft.longitude) / 2, distanceHeight)

    val radiusInMeters = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(distanceWidth.get(0).toString().toDouble(), 2.0))
            + Math.pow(distanceHeight.get(0).toString().toDouble(), 2.0)) / 2
    return radiusInMeters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: The following answer is for Google Maps JavaScript API v3

=-=-=-=-=-=-=

I think the answer would be: Yes, you can.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance), you can calculate distance between 2 points by: `computeDistanceBetween(LatLngFrom, LatLngTo)`

Also you can get the boundary of the map by using `getBounds()` method, which is in the [google.maps.Map class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

Comment: thanks for the reply but isn't these methods and these links refer to v3? which is only available for javascript right now?