# How to calculate visible area from zoom? google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to achieve that camera update would center between two positions
**BUT** if resulting zoom level is bigger than 12 it should be set to 12.

So i need some:

```
 CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,padding);
```

But instead of `padding` there should be max zoom level.

My solution requires that i calculate exact screen bounds that will be after camera update and here i got stuck.

Comment: Is your problem related to getting the zoom level value after the camera has been positioned, or setting the camera zoom level after determining whether the current zoom level is >= 12?

Comment: i need zoom level to be <= 12 as result, while bounding two or more coordinates. 
'newLatLngZoom' doesn't guarantee that both coordinates will be visible to user.

Comment: `'newLatLngZoom' doesn't guarantee that both coordinates will be visible to user.` yes it does, otherwise what would `padding` be for?

Comment: @pskink Word "both" stands for two `LatLng` objects. This means that there is two places on the map.

Comment: you use `LatLngBounds` as a parameter so any number of `LatLng` in those bounds will be visible: in other words the whole `LatLngBounds` will be visible with the optional `padding` on four screen edges

Comment: `LatLngBounds` doesn't guarantee that zoom level will be 12 or less (if coordinates doesn't fit). it could zoom in way too much if coordinates ~100m apart.

Comment: so you want two or more points to be visible or not? if you limit the zoom it may turn out that no point will be visible

Comment: There can be no such scenario, since i want to limit maximum zoom not minmum (lesser zoom level - more area is visible on the map).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate map screen bounds, you should use [`VisibleRegion`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion)

```
VisibleRegion visibleRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
```

- read also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29222864/3191896) question, may be similar to what you need.