# Google Maps two finger pinch/stretch callbacks

Tags: android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment, android-gesture

In my map, I am trying to capture zoom in/out using `ScaleGestureDetector` but I am **never** receiving any callbacks to either of `onScale` or `onScaleBegin` or `onScaleEnd`.

In my Fragment's `onCreateView`, I initialize:

`scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new simpleOnScaleGestureListener());`

And I implement the callbacks like so:

```
public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startScale = detector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.d(TAG, "::onScale:: " + detector.getScaleFactor());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "::onScaleBegin:: " + detector.getScaleFactor());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "::onScaleEnd:: " + detector.getScaleFactor());
        endScale = detector.getScaleFactor();

}
```

Also, is it fair to assume that the callbacks will be called continuously whenever the user zooms in/out?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past the issue of getting callbacks. Essentially, two things:

1. In your activity/fragment, implement, `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener`
2. In `onMapReady()`, `call mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);`
3. Hence, override `onCameraIdle()`:

`@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
   Log.i(TAG, "::onCameraIdle::" +               mMap.getCameraPosition().toString());
 }`

to get lat/long, zoom, tilt and bearing, essentially `CameraPosition`.

I found a way to get radius in meters by referring to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222864/get-radius-of-visible-map-in-android/29264003#comment67545444_29264003)

```
VisibleRegion vr = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();

Location center = new Location("center");
center.setLatitude(vr.latLngBounds.getCenter().latitude);
center.setLongitude(vr.latLngBounds.getCenter().longitude);

//Location("radiusLatLng") as mentioned in google maps sample
Location farVisiblePoint = new Location("radiusLatLng");
farVisiblePoint.setLatitude(vr.farLeft.latitude);
farVisiblePoint.setLongitude(vr.farLeft.longitude);

radius = center.distanceTo(farVisiblePoint);
```