# Google Maps get visible area radius for zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, geography

I'm building an app where I load data from the API in `onCameraIdle`. The request needs the **target location** and a **radius** in which to give me the results.

The code I use to get the radius from the current camera is:

```
/**
 * @param map The Map on which to compute the radius.
 * @return The circle radius of the area visible on map, in meters.
 */
public float getRadiusVisibleOnMap(GoogleMap map) {
    VisibleRegion visibleRegion = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();

    LatLng farRight = visibleRegion.farRight;
    LatLng farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft;
    LatLng nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight;
    LatLng nearLeft = visibleRegion.nearLeft;

    float[] distanceWidth = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(
            (farRight.latitude + nearRight.latitude) / 2,
            (farRight.longitude + nearRight.longitude) / 2,
            (farLeft.latitude + nearLeft.latitude) / 2,
            (farLeft.longitude + nearLeft.longitude) / 2,
            distanceWidth
    );


    float[] distanceHeight = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(
            (farRight.latitude + nearRight.latitude) / 2,
            (farRight.longitude + nearRight.longitude) / 2,
            (farLeft.latitude + nearLeft.latitude) / 2,
            (farLeft.longitude + nearLeft.longitude) / 2,
            distanceHeight
    );

    float radius;

    if (distanceWidth[0] > distanceHeight[0]) {
        radius = distanceWidth[0];
    } else {
        radius = distanceHeight[0];
    }

    return radius;
}
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222864/get-radius-of-visible-map-in-android)

There are some cases where **I need to get the radius knowing only the zoom level**, so that the info is already loaded on the map when the zoom animation is finished.

I tried to adjust the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002563/android-how-do-i-set-the-zoom-level-of-map-view-to-1-km-radius-around-my-curren?rq=1) to get the radius knowing the zoom level instead of the other way around.

```
public int getZoomLevel(Circle circle) {
    if (circle != null) {
        double radius = circle.getRadius();
        double scale = radius / 500;
        zoomLevel = (int) (16 - Math.log(scale) / Math.log(2));
    }
    return zoomLevel;
}
```

I got the formula: [image: formula]

The formula is incorrect. It doesn't output the right dimensions. For a zoom level of 14, I get a radius dimension of 2.697331km using the camera's VisibleRegion. If I calculate the radius using the formula, the result is 0.008km.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: The formula I got to for calculating the radius is incorrect. It doesn't output the right dimensions. For a zoom level of 14, I get a radius dimension of 2.697331km using the camera's VisibleRegion. If I calculate the radius using the formula, the result is 0.008km.

Comment: Do you have more than one latitude longitude on the visual base? If then I can give you the logic to calculate radius out of that. I mean zoom based on more than one lat / lon

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I need the radius before I initiate the following command:
       map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, zoomLevel), callback);

I have the location : LatLng and zoomLevel : float

Comment: I mean if you have Lat/Lon for Location 1 and Lat/Lon for Location 2 and Lat/Lon for Location 3, Then I can give you the formula to calculate the zoom based on all these locations

Comment: No, I do not have multiple locations. I do not want to set the camera in such way that 3 locations are shown simultaneously. For that I would use a LatLngBounds where to hold the coordinates and CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds.
I need to know the camera's VisibleRegion before the zoom animation is finished.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like best practice for you is to find a minimal radius value that fits the map rectangle inside.

You were almost there, use the modified function below which uses [Pythagorean theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCzlL.png) to find the minimal radius required to contain the map's "rectangle".

[image]

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(() -> {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
        double radiusInMeters = getMapVisibleRadius();
        double radiusInKilometers = radiusInMeters / 1000;
        double latitude = cameraPosition.target.latitude;
        double longitude = cameraPosition.target.longitude;

        // TODO you take it from here, 
        // I use firebase to get relevant markers based on the lat,long,radius

    });
}


private double getMapVisibleRadius() {
    VisibleRegion visibleRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();

    float[] distanceWidth = new float[1];
    float[] distanceHeight = new float[1];

    LatLng farRight = visibleRegion.farRight;
    LatLng farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft;
    LatLng nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight;
    LatLng nearLeft = visibleRegion.nearLeft;

    Location.distanceBetween(
            (farLeft.latitude + nearLeft.latitude) / 2,
            farLeft.longitude,
            (farRight.latitude + nearRight.latitude) / 2,
            farRight.longitude,
            distanceWidth
    );

    Location.distanceBetween(
            farRight.latitude,
            (farRight.longitude + farLeft.longitude) / 2,
            nearRight.latitude,
            (nearRight.longitude + nearLeft.longitude) / 2,
            distanceHeight
    );

    double radiusInMeters = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceWidth[0], 2) + Math.pow(distanceHeight[0], 2)) / 2;
    return radiusInMeters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an update for everyone who is using [Maps Compose Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose) I can recommend this extension function on `CameraPositionState` to directly get the visible radius:

```
fun CameraPositionState.visibleRadius(): Double {
    this.projection?.visibleRegion?.let { visibleRegion ->
        val distanceWidth = FloatArray(1)
        val distanceHeight = FloatArray(1)
        val farRight = visibleRegion.farRight
        val farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft
        val nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight
        val nearLeft = visibleRegion.nearLeft

        Location.distanceBetween(
            (farLeft.latitude + nearLeft.latitude) / 2,
            farLeft.longitude,
            (farRight.latitude + nearRight.latitude) / 2,
            farRight.longitude,
            distanceWidth
        )
        Location.distanceBetween(
            farRight.latitude,
            (farRight.longitude + farLeft.longitude) / 2,
            nearRight.latitude,
            (nearRight.longitude + nearLeft.longitude) / 2,
            distanceHeight
        )
        return sqrt(
            distanceWidth[0].toDouble().pow(2.0) + distanceHeight[0].toDouble().pow(2.0)
        ) / 2
    }
    return -1.0
}
```

Later you can then use it like this in you UI code:

```
LaunchedEffect(cameraPositionState.isMoving) {
    if (!cameraPositionState.isMoving) {
        viewModel.onUpdateVisibleRadius(
            visibleRadius = cameraPositionState.visibleRadius(),
        )
    }
}
```