# Property 'distanceBetween' does not exist on type '{ new (): Location; prototype: Location; }'

Tags: angular, typescript, location, maps

I want to write [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29264003) code in typescript:

I get correct visibleRegion, but I can't understand how to write code Location.distanceBetween(..)  for calculate distance.

I have this code:

```
this.gMap = event.object.gMap;
var visibleRegion = this.gMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
var farRight = visibleRegion.farRight;
var farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft;
var nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight;
var nearLeft = visibleRegion.nearLeft;
var diagonalDistance = new float[1]; //Cannot find name 'float'.ts(2304)

var farLeft = visibleRegion.farLeft;
var nearRight = visibleRegion.nearRight;

Location.distanceBetween( //Property 'distanceBetween' does not exist on type '{ new (): Location; prototype: Location; }'.ts(2339)
  farLeft.latitude,
  farLeft.longitude,
  nearRight.latitude,
  nearRight.longitude,
  diagonalDistance
);

return diagonalDistance[0] / 2;
```

Have you any idea please? I wont to write in Typescript Code. Nativescript/ Angular

Comment: Can you show the import of `Location` ?

Comment: No, I cant import Location. From ?

Comment: If you use `Location.distanceBetween`, you have to import `Location`, otherwise the code won't know where to find it...